# cakephp delete not working in model

Tags: php, cakephp

```
class Model extends AppModel{

  public function deleteSomething(){

    if (empty($this->id)) {
      return false;
    }

    $this->read();

    $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);

    $db->begin($this);

    if (! $this->delete($this->id, true)) {
      $db->rollback($this);
      return false;
   }
   return $db->commit($this);
}
```

For some reason this will not delete?? I have debugged the id and it is correct.
Any ideas? Am I missing something?
}

Comment: Maybe you have some foreign key that prevents the deletion? Did you try to delete it manually?

Comment: Hi, do you mean manually as in running an SQL script directly on the table? If this is the case, then yes I have and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any commit function. I think it should be:

```
if (! $this->delete($this->id, true)) {
    $db->rollback($this);
    return false;
}
$db->commit($this);  
return true;
```

Comment: Sorry I did have one there, just missed it off when I copied it. I have edited it into the question now. Sorry

Comment: Tried your code in my app, everything works fine. You need to check problems in other place.

Comment: I have debugged the delete() and it says it ran successfully, with the right id. Then I debugged the commit and it returns true. But I go into the DB and the row is still there??

Answer (score 0):

```
public function delete()
    {
        $this->layout = 'iphone_gps';
        $this->set('title_for_layout','Iphone GPS, LLC : Companies');
        $this->Companies = $this->request->data;
        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        foreach($this->Companies as $ids){
            $this->Companie->deleteAll(array('Companie.company_id' => $ids));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash($this->deleted);
        $this->redirect('index');
    }
```

make one delete function in controller ...
then next in index.ctp page

```
echo "<br>".$this->Form->input('Delete',array('class' => 'youreclass','style' => 'display:block;width:100px;','onclick'=>"return confirm('Are you sure for delete data?')",array('type'=>'hidden')));
```